# Convert column to rows and get the latest value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to convert my columns to rows and for it to show the latest value,

Here's a sample of what my database looks like:

Table 1:

```
+----+-----------------+
| id |    location     |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | 2012/East/A/Flw |
|  2 | 2012/East/A/Lvl |
|  3 | 2012/East/B/Flw |
|  4 | 2012/East/B/Lvl |
+----+-----------------+
```

Table 2:

```
+------------+-------+------------------+
| locationid | value |      tstamp      |
+------------+-------+------------------+
|          1 |    10 | 2013-11-18 10:00 |
|          2 |    21 | 2013-11-18 10:00 |
|          3 |     5 | 2013-11-18 10:00 |
|          4 |    30 | 2013-11-18 10:00 |
|          1 |     5 | 2013-11-19 11:00 |
|          2 |    20 | 2013-11-19 11:00 |
|          3 |    15 | 2013-11-19 11:00 |
|          4 |    28 | 2013-11-19 11:00 |
+------------+-------+------------------+
```

I was hoping I can get the output to be like this:

```
+----------+-----+-----+
| location | Flw | Lvl |
+----------+-----+-----+
| East A   |   5 |  20 |
| East B   |  15 |  28 |
+----------+-----+-----+
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you really store your data in location as a slash delimited list?

Comment: Ok, let me try to elaborate on Bill's question: ***why*** are you storing your data as a slash-delimited list? Especially when you know that each of those parts actually has independent meaning?

Comment: I can't edit how its being stored. I can't change it. This is just a data given to me for me to work on.

Comment: How does one know the `1|5` is the Flw and not the lvl when the locationid is 1?

Comment: actually, it is. i'm trying to find diff answers on how to work on this. cause using `MAX` is not working for me. It's almost correct, i'm just having problems on getting the latest value

Comment: @billinkc Cause for locationid `1` it indicates that its Flw on East A on table 1 and then if locatiodid is `2` its Lvl on East A..

Comment: Ah, I see now. You could really use another table to link table1 id(1,2) together as well as (3,4). Pity you can't modify your data structure. And that you're working with mysql

Comment: And that you are mixing several distinct problems into a single question.

Comment: If the Location column is not possible right now, can you atleast help me on how I can get the latest value and then convert the columns to rows?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table2 T2 WHERE T2.tstamp = (SELECT MAX(TI2.tstamp FROM table2 TI2 WHERE TI2.locationid = T2.locationid)` That finds the most recent row in t2 for all the locationid

Comment: It is good that you yourself can distinguish those as separate problems. Please search this site or Stack Overflow for "greatest-n-per-group" problems to solve the latest value bit, and for "pivot" to solve the other one. Don't forget to include "mysql" into the search string.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage dynamic SQL to achieve this

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(
         'MAX(CASE WHEN locationid IN(', ids, 
         ') THEN value END) `', col, '`'))
  INTO @sql
  FROM 
(
  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(location, '/', -1) col, GROUP_CONCAT(id) ids
    FROM table1
   GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(location, '/', -1)
) q;

SET @sql = CONCAT(
   'SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(location, ''/'', 2), ''/'', -1), '' '',
                  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(location, ''/'', -2), ''/'', 1)) location, ',
   @sql,
   '  FROM table1 l LEFT JOIN
    (
      SELECT t.locationid, t.value
        FROM 
      (
        SELECT locationid, MAX(tstamp) tstamp
          FROM table2
         GROUP BY locationid
      ) q JOIN table2 t 
          ON q.locationid = t.locationid
         AND q.tstamp = t.tstamp
    ) d
        ON l.id = d.locationid
     GROUP BY CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(location, ''/'', 2), ''/'', -1), '' '',
                     SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(location, ''/'', -2), ''/'', 1))'
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Output:

```
| LOCATION | FLW | LVL |
|----------|-----|-----|
|   East A |   5 |  20 |
|   East B |  15 |  28 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84f11/16)** demo

Comment: Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?